# Como usar "for" para calcular a soma dos números pares de um array com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for, soma

Estou estudando JavaScript e preciso criar um código para calcular a soma de todos os números pares usando um laço `for`.
Escrevi como está abaixo:

```
const numbers = [2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12];
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        sum+=numbers[i];
    }
}

console.log("Sum:", sum);
```

Desta forma, o resultado está dando 29, no entanto o correto seria 28 e não consegui identificar onde eu estou errando.

Comment: Tem 2 erros, o primeiro é que na operação de mod você está aplicando o índice `i % 2` ao invés de aplicar o valor, para aplicar o valor no mod use `numbers[i] % 2`, o segundo erro é que o for() está usando `<=` quando deveria usar `<`, o índice começa no zero, então o ultimo índice tem que ser menor que o índice incrementado, se usar <= você vai tentar obter um item que não existe no índice, por exemplo, você tem 7 índices no seu exemplo: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6; veja que ultimo índice é o 6, se usar <= o código vai tentar pegar o índice 7, que não existe.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O que o algoritmo pede é que você descubra se o **número que está no *array*** é par, e se for deve incluí-lo em uma soma, certo?

Seu código está pegando o cada o valor do *array* para somar e somando direitinho. E está fazendo isso condicionalmente, então em alguns casos ele pegará o valor para somar ou não.

O erro está nessa seleção. Está verificando se é par certinho. Mas que número está pegando para verificar se é par? Está pegando o **número que está no *array*** para ver se é par? Não, está pegando o valor do contador do laço. È isso que deveria fazer? Então o que tem que pegar?

Está pegando 2, 5, 10 e 12, que são as posições pares do *array*. 5 Não é par, e 4 que é par não pegou por estar em posição ímpar. Agora imagina se no *array* a segunda e terceira posição tivessem números invertidos, daria o resultado certo por coincidência e acharia que o algoritmo está certo, olha o perigo de testar baseando-se no resultado.

```js
const numbers = [2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12];
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) sum += numbers[i];
console.log("Sum:", sum);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/SumEven.js).

Quando acontece isso pode mudar o código para mandar imprimir os valores que estão sendo usados em cada passo para facilitar o entendimento. Isso chama-se *debugar*. E acompanhando o que o código faz chega-se no erro.